# How can I change createCriteria (deprecated) to CriteriaQuery in this method?

Tags: java, hibernate

codigo is a primary key for search an item, in the case estado (state)

I'm trying to update this code, it was from hibernate bellow 5 version

```java
public class GenericDAOnew<Entidade> {
        
    private Class<Entidade> classe;
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GenericDAOnew() {
        // APIreflection
        this.classe = (Class<Entidade>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }    

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Entidade buscar(Long codigo){
                
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getFabricaDeSessoes().openSession();
                
        try {
            Criteria consulta = sessao.createCriteria(classe);
            // adicionando restricao como o where do sql
            consulta.add(Restrictions.idEq(codigo));            
            Entidade resultado = (Entidade) consulta.uniqueResult();
            return resultado;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = sessao.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Entidade> criteria = builder.createQuery( classe );
Root<Entidade> root = criteria.from( classe );
criteria.select( root );
criteria.where( builder.equal( root.get( "id" ), codigo ) ); // Entidade_.id

Entidade resultado = sessao.createQuery( criteria ).getSingleResult();
```

If you are going to use [JPA static metamodel](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/topical/html_single/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html) which allows Criteria queries to be constructed in a strongly-typed manner, you can replace hardcoded field name `"id"` by something like `Entidade_.id`

Comment: That works nicelly! thank you so much sir! 


Hibernate: select estado0_.codigo as codigo1_2_, estado0_.nome as nome2_2_, estado0_.sigla as sigla3_2_ from Estado estado0_ where estado0_.codigo=2
Estado : Rio de Janeiro sigla : RJ codigo : 2